# How to get dex transaction data like dextools or dexscreener

Tags: blockchain, solidity, binance-smart-chain

I want to implement a product, similar to DexTools/Dexscreener

https://dexscreener.com/
https://dextools.io/

Tracking and charting your DEX in realtime.
How should I obtain transaction data？
Where do you get the data source？

Answer (score 1):

I believe, anybody correct me if Im wrong because I never done it before, that you would have to use a dex api (dezentralized exchange api) such as bitquery to fetch the data:

https://bitquery.io/products/dex

I am sure that there are many APIs like that. It might be a bit of a learning curve to use them.

Comment: And I believe that most of these APIs use graphql (https://graphql.org/) as the query language.

Comment: Here is actually a bitquery tutorial on how to do that (with graphql): https://bitquery.io/blog/ethereum-dex-graphql-api . And then there is graphQL.js which lets you use graphQL with javascript. It also looks like that bitquery is free with the developer version: https://bitquery.io/pricing . It will definitely be a bit of a learning curve though. But it's always like that. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you sir.
Companies like BitQuery, I want to know, where do they get their data, how do they integrate their data? This is the real data source

Comment: Oh i coudlnt tell you that. I can look it up. Maybe bitquery or other dex software are opensource and you can check it there. Why do you need that tho? I thiught h just wanted to create a software similar to dex scanner

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is achieved using the event logs of contracts. For example, a Uniswap LP pair has events and the factory contract has events of new pairs being created. From there you could poll the events with websockets or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Blockin.ai is a Node-as-a-service Provider, as well as RPC Endpoints, & API Provider as well.  They support 22+ different Blockchains currently.

They have a free subscription plan for individual users, and an Enterprise tier for more on demand applications.